# Laravel 5 Resource route define create URL::route('') in view

Tags: routes, laravel-5.3

I have a href and i want to add URL::route('create') to the url like this

```
<a href="{{URL::route('xxx.create') }}{{$projectfornav[0]->afas_id}}"> XXX </a>
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('/xxx/{id}', 'XXXController');
```

Error:

```
Route [create.xxx] not defined. (View:.........
```

But this doesn't work. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I define a route inside a group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
   Route::resource('user', 'userController');
});
```

And this is how I create the show URL for UserId 123

```
URL::route('admin.user.show', 123)
```

I think you have to change

```
<a href="{{URL::route('xxx.create') }}{{$projectfornav[0]->afas_id}}"> XXX </a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{URL::route('xxx.create', $projectfornav[0]->afas_id) }}"> XXX </a>
```